# are all tables save in the same path

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created sqlite database and table called GEOLOC.db and NODE_00 respectively in an App called App1, and populated the the table with 10 records.
then i created another App called App2 and in it i just referred to the GEOLOC.db and NODE_00 that were created in App1 as follows

```
//App2
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GEOLOC.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "NODE_00";

private Context mCtx = null;
..
..
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");
}
```

despite i created that database and the table in App1, when i examined the number of rows contained in NODE_00 from App2 i received the same number
of rows which is 10 rows.

i have two questions:

1-can you explain why how in App2 the table NODE_00 still contain the same data?

2- i want to create an index on two columns of the table NODE_00, should create them in onCreate from App1?

Comment: can you explain it more clearly

Comment: In Android, no app can access the data of another app except through defined systems such as a ContentProvider.  What you are saying is happening is impossible so you are likely making a mistake somewhere (or explaining very badly).